# Pass non-static member function as a callback

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I found several similar questions, but the solutions didn't suit my case.
In a C++ method, I call a C api, which takes a callback as one of its parameter.

```
class A
{

   herr_t methodA(some parameters) {....}

   void methodB(some parameters)
   {
       ....

       int status =  CAPI(other parameters, callback, last parameter);
   }

};
```

The prototype of CAPI is

```
herr_t CAPI( some parameters, H5L_iterate_t op, other parameters);
```

H5L_iterate_t is defined by

```
herr_t (*H5L_iterate_t)( hid_t g_id, const char *name, 
                         const H5L_info_t *info, void *op_data)
```

methodA has the same signature as H5L_iterate_t.
In methodB,

```
status = CAPI(..., **(H5L_iterate_t )std::bind(&A::methodA, this,
              std::placeholders::_1)**, ...);
```

The compile error I got was "Can't convert from ... to H5L_iterate_t".  I'm wondering what's the right way to pass the non static member function as a callback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Member methods pointers and function pointer are not compatible. You might try to write a free function, s static member method or s stateless lambda to give as a callback which calls the actual member method and provide `this` through `op_data`.

Comment: For C callbacks, I believe  you need a function pointer.  So it can't be a non-static member function.

Comment: I know a static member function or a plain c function can do that job. But I need the callback to change the state of the object.

Answer (score 2):

C APIs offering a callback almost always follow this pattern:

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef void(*callback_function)(void* data);    

    typedef int handle_type;

    void do_something_with_callback(handle_type, callback_function, void *data);
}
```

The idea being that whatever you pass as the `data` argument when `do_something_with_callback` is called, will be passed to the `callback_function`.

You can use this user data to pass a pointer to your c++ object's address, which you can then cast back to a pointer to your object type:

```
struct my_object
{
    void initiate()
    {
        // call the C interface, passing our c-style callback function with
        // a pointer to this class as the user data
        do_something_with_callback(handle_, &callback_launch_function, this);
    }

private:
    static void callback_launch_function(void * data) {
        // the data will always be a pointer to my_object - 
        // because that's what we passed.
        auto self = reinterpret_cast<my_object*>(data);
        self->handle_it();
    }

    // this is our c++style callback
    void handle_it()
    {

    }

    handle_type handle_;
};
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but is it a problem to call the non-static handle_it() from static function?

Comment: @Wqh provided that the `data` argument really is a pointer to a `my_object` (and in this case, we have ensured that it is) then this is perfectly legal and correct.

Comment: @Wqh: no, it is not a problem, because the code is calling `handle_it()` via a pointer to an object, so `handle_it()` receives a `this` pointer as expected.

Comment: You are right, that's not a problem and I like this solution. But I added  void do_something_with_callback(handle_type, callback_function, void *data)
{
   printf("in do something with callback\n");
   callback_function();
}  And other printf in the callback_lauch_function. I didn't see the text printed out from callback_lauch_function. In gdb, I didn't see the callback was called. Very strange.

Comment: I think I need to pass the data to the callback, but that the callback still doesn't work. void do_something_with_callback(handle_type, callback_function, void *data)
{
   printf("in do something with callback\n");
   callback_function((void*)data);
}

Comment: I have to change the declaration to  void do_something_with_callback(handle_type, callback_function callback, void *data);  makes the call by  callback(data)    Works for me now. Thanks!